# Finding how many solutions does $f(x)=\ln x-kx$ has for $k>\frac 1 e$ and logarithmic inequality question

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, logarithms

> Find how many solutions does $f(x)=\ln x-kx$ has for $k>\frac 1 e$.

$f<0$ at $x\to \infty$ and $x\to 0$. The derivative has a solution only at $x=\frac 1 k$.

So place that point in $f$ and we'll want to check when $f(\frac 1 k)>0$ and $f(\frac 1 k)<0$

Now I'm getting confused here:

$f(\frac 1 k)>0\to \ln \frac 1 k > 1$ so $e^1>\frac 1 k\to k>\frac 1 e$ but it should be the opposite, so my question is why does the inequality 'flip'?

Comment: Yes. Why does it flip?! The exponential function is increasing. The proper thing to do is to keep the inequality sign as it is.